# How do I fix the @MapKeyJoinColumn attribute adding a products_key column in Hibernate Java mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to build Entity relationship using Java Hibernate and I'm getting some difficulties setting a `@OneToMany` Map field.

This is roughly my set-up:

## Class Store

```
@Entity
public class Store {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "key.store", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapKey(name = "key.id")
    private Map<Long, Product> products;
...
}
```

A store can have many products.

## Class Product

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProductKey key;

    private String name;

    private double price;
...
}
```

## Class ProductKey

```
@Embeddable
public class ProductKey implements Serializable {
    private static int ID_COUNTER = 0;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "store_id", nullable = false)
    private Store store;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Integer id;
...
}
```

Each product can belong to one store only - hence the `@OneToOne` relationship here. It also has its own ID.

## Class Basket

```
@Entity
public class Basket {
    @EmbeddeId
    private BasketKey key;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "key.basket", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Map<Integer, BaskedProduct> products;
...
}
```

## Class BasketKey

```
@Embeddable
public class BasketKey implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "store_id", nullable = false)
    private Store store;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_name", nullable = false)
    private User user;
...
}
```

Each basket belongs to one user and one store.

## Class BaskedProduct

```
@Entity
public class BaskedProduct {
    @EmbeddedId
    private BaskedProductKey key;

    private int quantity;
...
}
```

## Class BaskedProductKey

```
@Embeddable
public class BaskedProductKey implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "product_id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "store_id", referencedColumnName = "store_id")
    })
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "basket_store_id", referencedColumnName = "store_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "basket_cart_username", referencedColumnName = "cart_user_name")
    })
    private Basket basket;
...
}
```

BaskedProduct represents copied of chosen product that a user has added to his relevant basket.

I have a problem with the `products` field of class `Basket`. I want to map product ID to the BaskedProduct. But the `@MapKeyJoinColumn` attribute adds a `products_key` column to the `baskedproducts` table instead of retrieving data from the table.
What did I do wrong and how can I fix this?